# colnames of a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, names

This might sound trivial, but I am facing an issue in finding column name of a dataframe(with 1 column)

```
> a <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c("a", "a","c","d","r"))
> a
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 a
3 3 c
4 4 d
5 5 r
> colnames(a)
[1] "x" "y"
> names(a)
[1] "x" "y"
> a1 <- a[,1]
> class(a1)
[1] "numeric"
> a1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> a1 <- as.data.frame(a[,1])
> a1
  a[, 1]
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
> colnames(a1)
[1] "a[, 1]"
> names(a1)
[1] "a[, 1]"
>
```

I am selecting 1 column from the dataframe "a", I want the output to be "x" when I query for the column name of a1. Appreciate help on this. Thanks

Comment: when you subset 'a' use the `drop` argument: `a1 <- a[,1,drop=FALSE]`

Comment: @user20650 You should write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Data
a <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c("a", "a","c","d","r"), z = 1:5)

class(a)
#[1] "data.frame"

# Subset a
a1 <- a[,1]

class(a1)
is.vector(a1)
is.data.frame(a1)
```

This is a numeric vector called a1 (not x). Look at the `drop` argument in `?"["`: the default is `drop =TRUE`. As there is only one column, a[,1] is coerced to a numeric vector and the column name is lost. When you subsequently pass the vector to `data.frame`, the columns will take the name of the vector passed to it (if it is named), hence

```
names(data.frame(a1))
# [1] "a1"
```

So use `drop = FALSE` when subsetting to avoid the reduction - a1 will be a one column data.frame

```
(a1 <- a[,1, drop = FALSE])
#  x
#1 1
#2 2
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this provides any further enlightenment, but it's interesting nonetheless.  It seems like this may be how `drop = FALSE` came about.

```
> a1 <- structure(data.frame(a[,1]), .Names = names(a)[1])
> colnames(a1)
# [1] "x"
```

**But you could really just do this:**

```
> a1 <- a["x"]
> colnames(a1)
# [1] "x"
```